# How to edit value in a specific td after clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here's my `button`

```
<button id="Modify" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>Modify</button>
```

Here's my script for `Modify button`

```
$("#Modify").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#cLoanOut2 tr.active').attr('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to modify this order?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
            $.ajax({  
                url : "<?php echo $server_name; ?>/emcis_coopmain/process/PHP_groceryReleasingProcess.php",
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : {
                    empgrocmstID:id,
                    todo:"Modify"
                },
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert('Order Modified',function(){
                    $("#Modify").attr("disabled", true);
                    });
                    loadTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

And the `td` in my `php`

```
$html .= "<td class='qty_ordered' style='text-align:right'>$qty_ordered</td>";
```

**How can I edit the value on that td after I clicked the modify button?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: ('#tdid').text('newvalue')

Comment: @Pekka will you create a chat room where we can talk the three of us?

Comment: as suggested by Rey you can set the td to editable like this http://jsfiddle.net/kw1uv2cv/

Answer (score 0):

If the class is specific for that `<td>` then as simple as

```
$("td.qty_ordered").html("<Your new value here>");
```

Also, if my assumption is correct, you change the `td`value inside your `success()` function in your `ajax()` call.

Mabuhay!

Comment: Yes I am but please speak english here at all times. :) Edit your comment.

Comment: I mean, After I clicked the button then the td will be an input type where I can change the value that is on that td then the database will update.

Comment: Try playing with `contenteditable="true"` if it suits your requirement.

Comment: If modify button was clicked? How can I save the new value that I typed?